# Why does Java interpret some IPv6 addresses as IPv4?

Tags: java, ip, ipv6, ipv4

Why are certain IPv6 addresses converted to IPv4 addresses when using `InetAddress.getByName`?

For example, I expect both of these addresses `::f:f:f`, `::ffff:f:f` to be converted to `Inet6Address`

However, this one `::ffff:f:f` becomes `Inet4Address`

```java
import java.net.InetAddress;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Interpreted as IPv6
    var address = InetAddress.getByName("::f:f:f");
    System.out.println(address); // /0:0:0:0:0:f:f:f
    System.out.println(address.getClass()); // class java.net.Inet6Address
    
    // Interpreted as IPv4
    address = InetAddress.getByName("::ffff:f:f");
    System.out.println(address); // /103.30.217.152
    System.out.println(address.getClass()); // class java.net.Inet4Address
  }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ for the Special IPv6 address ranges. This excludes the IPv6 multicast range (`ff00::/8` that has scopes and flags, and a separate IANA page), and the current Global IPv6 address range (`2000::/3`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPv6 addresses in the `::ffff:0:0/96` range are IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses. This is a special range to represent IPv4 addresses in the IPv6 addressing format, so those actually are IPv4 addresses, not IPv6 addresses. This is explained in *[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)*:

> [2.5.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.1).
> IPv4-Mapped IPv6 Address
>
> A second type of IPv6 address that holds an embedded IPv4 address is
> defined. This address type is used to represent the addresses of IPv4
> nodes as IPv6 addresses. The format of the "IPv4-mapped IPv6 address"
> is as follows:
>
> ```
>    |                80 bits               | 16 |      32 bits        |
>    +--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
>    |0000..............................0000|FFFF|    IPv4 address     |
>    +--------------------------------------+----+---------------------+
> ```
>
> See [[RFC4038](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4038)] for background on
> the usage of the "IPv4-mapped IPv6 address".